# Design pattern for collapse but not entirely

Tags: design-patterns, layout, data-display

I have a bunch of cards in a 2 column layout in my grid. If there are more than 2 items to display I want to show only 2 of them and hide the remaining behind a "Show all" button.

What is this design pattern called? Collapsed view? Preview? Accordion? Snapshot?

[image]

Comment: When there's a button to load results, it's often called a "load more" pattern.

Comment: It's right below the cards

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Updated the question with Figma

Answer (score 1):

### Lazy Load

> Lazy loading (also known as asynchronous loading) is a design pattern commonly used in computer programming and mostly in web design and development to defer initialization of an object until the point at which it is needed.

<sub>*[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)*</sub>

This is the structural name, but in the UI the more specific name is:

### Load More

> The optimal solution for loading new products is the intersection of the “Load more” button and infinite scrolling in the form of lazy-loading.

<sub>*Source [smashingmagazine.com](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/pagination-infinite-scrolling-load-more-buttons/#load-more-for-categories)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be related to an accordion with horizontal behavior. My 2¢

Comment: Doesn't an accordion always collapse entirely?

Answer (score 0):

They call it "Progressive disclosure". The "Show more" button is just one of the ways to show a chunk of data and provide more on demand.

More about [progressive disclosure at nngroup.com](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/progressive-disclosure/)